# Sitecore - multiple instances of a sublayout on a page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have created some reusable components for our site and have hit a problem when trying to add more than one instance of these component to a page. This is an issue because Sitecore needs the placeholder key to be unique. Does this mean you can never add more than one instance of a sublayout with a placeholder on to the same page?

Example:

Two column sublayout - placeholders 2column-col1 and 2column-col2
Three column sublayout - placeholders 3column-col1, 3column-col2 and 3column-col3
On the page add a two column sublayout, a three column sublayout and then another two column sublayout
There are now 2 placeholders with the name 2column-col1 and 2 placeholders with the name 2column-col2

Is there any way around this? We thought of dynamically creating the placeholder key in the user control code behind but this causes problems if you want to use placeholder settings.

It seems that it would be a common thing to want to do. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is dynamically create the placeholder keys to get the desired functionality and then manually create 5-6 placeholder setting items and duplicate the settings for all of them. I have done this in one project and it works well even though it's very ugly.

If you are using sitecore 6.4+ you might even be able to use cloned items to create the placeholder settings. This way you will be able to control the allowed sub-layouts from the original item and all the rest will just inherit the values.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a duplicate of your SDN post, but for reference I will link my blog post (with prototype solution code) here as well.

http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/Dynamic%20Placeholder%20Keys%20Prototype.aspx

Comment: -1 as the link no longer works (Sitecore license error!), so the answer is currently unusable.

Comment: Further to previous comment, the blog is viewable from the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:egZb98GYlasJ:www.techphoria414.com/Blog/Dynamic%2520Placeholder%2520Keys%2520Prototype.aspx+http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/Dynamic%2520Placeholder%2520Keys%2520Prototype.aspx&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a), but ideally this answer wouldn't be dependant on the link. Can't remove the -1 sadly as I added it an hour ago!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the broken license. I think it's unfair to mark me down though, as it's a pretty involved answer.

Comment: I think it's fair as without the page it was no longer an answer without that detail, but kudos for sorting it out v. quickly. Didn't mean to offend (there are many cases on here with people long abandoning their accepted answers). If you edit the post it will allow me to remove the down-vote (which was my intention!).

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 6.3.1 there is a setting in web.config

```
  <!--  DUPLICATE PLACEHOLDERS
        Indicate whether to process duplicate placeholders
        Default value: false
  -->
  <setting name="Rendering.ProcessDuplicatePlaceholders" value="false" />
```

I think this setting is available on all versions of Sitecore 6.

You should give it a try and change it to "true".